# How can I get reactlog to render on its own webpage using flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I am successful in rendering 'reactlog' when I use flexdshboard, but it renders within the dashboard and is way too small in size - even for this minimal example.  How can I get it to render on its own webpage?

I tried using shiny::reactlogShow() after the session both with and without the reactlog_module_server() line in the server code to no avail. shiny::reactlogShow() brings up its own webpage, but it is blank.  Sample code is provided.

[image]

````
    ---
    title: "Untitled"
    output:
     flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
       orientation: rows
      
        
    runtime: shiny
    ---
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    
    
    library(shiny)
    library(reactlog)
    reactlog_enable()        # Enable reactlog
    library(flexdashboard)
    
    ```
    
    
    ###
    
    
    ```{r}
    
    ## Inputs
    
    
    shiny::numericInput(
       inputId = "a",
       label = "Input 'a'",
       value = 3
     
    )
    
    shiny::numericInput(
       inputId = "b",
       label = "Input 'b'",
       value = 4
     
    )
    
    ### start ui module
    reactlog_module_ui()
    
    
    ```
    
    
    ###
    
    
    ```{r}
    
    ## Output
    
    
    
    a2 <- eventReactive(input$a,
          { a <- input$a^2
            a 
      })
    
    b2 <- eventReactive(input$b,
          { b <- input$b^2
            b
      })
    
     c2 <- reactive(
       { x <- a2() + b2()
         x
      })
     
     c <- reactive(
       { y <- sqrt( c2() )
         y
     })
    
    
    
    renderPrint({
       
     c()
       
    })
    
    
    ### start server module
    reactlog_module_server()
````

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the calls to `reactlog_module_ui()` and  `reactlog_module_server()`.

While running your {reactlog} enabled dashboard, pressing Ctrl+F3 at any time will open the reactlog visulizer in a new window.

Comment: Thanks Hubert.  I removed the calls to reactlog_module_ui() and reactlog_module_server() as suggested. I'm running a Mac, so I used Cmd+F3 per instruction on https://rstudio.github.io/reactlog/.  When I do so, the screen displays the contents of my Desktop icons.  I tried Shift-F3, Ctrl-F3, and Cmd+Shift+F3 as possible alternatives with no success.

Comment: Under System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, I don't see the Cmd+F3 sequence being used by any application.

Comment: It works fine on my windows setup.... I'm not sure this applies on Mac but on windows I can open the dashboard in the web browser instead of RStudio default window. I would try that. You might also try to post again with macos tag...

Answer (score 0):

After conversing with the package's author, Dr. Schloerke, he graciously guided me in the right direction.  As with HubertL's response, he advised I remove the calls to reactlog_module_ui() and reactlog_module_server(). He added that I need to press “Cmd + Fn + F3” on my Mac keyboard.

That did the trick.  Reactlog now opens in its own full broswer.

[image]